# Select distinct() con Join en Laravel 5.5

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

he estado trabajando en una consulta sql que quiero replicar en Laravel 5.5 con eloquent, pero no logro que funcione.
Les explico, esta es mi consulta en SQL:

```
SELECT
empresas.companyname_cny,
empresas.ruc_cny,
municipios.municipality_mty,
ciudads.city_cty,
negocios.giro_detalle,
empresas.address_cny,
empresas.phone_cny,
empresas.email_cny,
empresas.id,
tpoders.id
FROM
empresas
INNER JOIN municipios ON empresas.municipalityid_cny = municipios.id
INNER JOIN ciudads ON empresas.cityid_cny = ciudads.id
INNER JOIN negocios ON empresas.gnegocio_id = negocios.id
INNER JOIN tpoders ON tpoders.empresa_id = empresas.id
GROUP BY empresas.companyname_cny
```

y mi resultado es a como lo espero:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al realizarla en laravel 5.5:

```
 $dem = DB::table('empresas')
      ->select(
        'empresas.companyname_cny',
        'tpoders.id',
        'empresas.id',
        'empresas.companyname_cny',
        'negocios.giro_detalle',
        'empresas.phone_cny',
        'empresas.email_cny',
        'ciudads.city_cty'
      )
      ->join('ciudads', 'empresas.cityid_cny','=','ciudads.id')
      ->join('negocios','empresas.gnegocio_id','=','negocios.id')
      ->join('tpoders','tpoders.empresa_id','=','empresas.id')
      ->distinct()->get(['empresas.companyname_cny']);
```

El resultado que me da es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna Empresa se repite. quiero evitar eso. Seguro es algo sencillo, pero he pasado el día buscando una solución y no he podido encontrarla. Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Saludos

Comment: el distinct debería ir inmediatamente despues del DB::table('empresas') y ya luego tu consulta como la tienes

Comment: es decir $dem = DB::table('empresas') ->distinct()->get(['empresas.companyname_cny']) y ya luego todo tu demas consulta

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, hice lo que me recomendastes pero me da un error: **Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::select does not exist**. `$dem = DB::table('empresas')
      ->distinct()->get(['empresas.companyname_cny'])
      ->select(
        'empresas.companyname_cny',
        'tpoders.id',
        'empresas.id',
        'empresas.companyname_cny',
        'negocios.giro_detalle',
        'empresas.phone_cny',`

Comment: cambia el get al final

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero sigue con el resultado inicial, me muestra 4 rows. he intentado varias formas, talves deba buscar otro metodo que no sean consultas, talves con los modelos.

Comment: mira la respuesta de este enlace https://laravel.io/forum/04-15-2014-use-distinct-on-joined-columns-with-query-builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dem = DB::table('empresas')
      ->select(
        'empresas.companyname_cny',
        'tpoders.id',
        'empresas.id',
        'empresas.companyname_cny',
        'negocios.giro_detalle',
        'empresas.phone_cny',
        'empresas.email_cny',
        'ciudads.city_cty'
      )
      ->join('ciudads', 'empresas.cityid_cny','=','ciudads.id')
      ->join('negocios','empresas.gnegocio_id','=','negocios.id')
      ->join('tpoders','tpoders.empresa_id','=','empresas.id')
      ->distinct()->get();
```

eso debería funcionar pero revisa que todas las columnas se repitan.

> El método distinct te permite forzar a la consulta a devolver
>   resultados distintos